# Can bonus rolls award you with warforged items?

Tags: world-of-warcraft

Can the bonus roll tokens ([Seal of Tempered Fate](http://www.wowhead.com/currency=994)) reward you with upgraded items when used in a Raid or World Boss?

As upgraded I'd count warforged, extra socket and bonus stats.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is **[possible](http://us.battle.net/wow/en/forum/topic/13594129286)** to get Warforged items with the bonus roll.

Although this post is from July 2014, there has been no indication that this has changed.

Unfortunately for me, my bonus rolls in this first week of Highmaul hasn't given me any loot, let alone Warforged! :)

Comment: They do, although from what I've been told there is maybe 2-3 max warforged Pieces in the loot table. So if they were already looted from the personal loot system by others it wont yield in a bonus roll since the bonus roll also rolls for whats left in the loot table.